# Onselect event doesn't fire on div

Tags: html, onselect

I have been unable to trigger an **onselect** event handler attached to a **<div>** element. Is it possible to force a **<div>** to emit **select** events?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onselect.asp), onSelect is only defined on input and textarea objects.

You may however try to catch the [MouseUp event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) and [retrieve the selected text](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp) in the current window/document.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you want by using `onMouseUp` event. See below...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="border: 1px solid #333" contentEditable="true" onMouseUp="checkMe()">Type text    here</div>

    </body>
    <script language="javascript">
    function checkMe() {
        var txt = "";

        if (window.getSelection) {
                txt = window.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.getSelection) {
            txt = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        alert("Selected text is " + txt);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm looking for but it doesn't consider the possibility that the user will use the keyboard to extend or move the selection. But then, binding the same logic to onKeyUp will  probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OnClick`.

`:select` only applies to some form elements.